# Stream with transform not work in background

Tags: flutter, stream, rxdart

In app, I use `stream.transform` and `CombineLatestStream.combine3` from `RxDart` to combine and merge multiple three streams in app for button validation. It is work well but if app stay in recent and background for long a time. `CombineLatestStream.combine3` not work and button not validate even all required fields are validate.

How this can be? How can I fix it? Here is my code for example

Controller code

```dart
  Function(String) get fillUserId => _userIdController.sink.add;

  Function(String) get fillPhoneNumber => _phoneNumberController.sink.add;

  Function(String) get fillPassword => _passwordController.sink.add;

  Stream<String> get userIdStream =>
      _userIdController.stream.transform(validateUserId);

  Stream<String> get phoneNumberStream =>
      _phoneNumberController.stream.transform(validatephoneNumber);

  Stream<String> get passwordStream =>
      _passwordController.stream.transform(validatePassword);

  Stream<bool> get submitValid => CombineLatestStream.combine3(
      userIdStream, phoneNumberStream, passwordStream, (u, p, pas) => true);
```

UI code

```
Widget loginButton(
      {required LoginBloc loginBloc, required bool isInternetAlive}) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: loginBloc.submitValid,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot loginSnapShot) {
        if (loginSnapShot.hasData) {
          formKey.currentState?.save();
        }
        return GradientButton(
          onClick: () {
            passwordFocusNode.unfocus();
            loginBloc.login(
              userId: userId!,
              password: password!,
              phoneNumber: phoneNumber!,
            );
            // passwordFocusNode.unfocus();
            _passCtrl.text = "";
            loginBloc.fillPassword("");
          },
          label: LOGIN_BTN_LABEL,
          isBtnDisable: loginSnapShot.hasData ? false : true,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

And From UI use `submitValid` stream with`streamBuilder` like that. But happening the error as above explanation. How can I fix?